# Multiple "Pages" Libraries

Tags: 2010

I hate the name of the "Pages" library. I'm looking to create multiple copies of the "Pages" library in one web with them all renamed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible (rather not recommended to have multiple *Pages* library in SharePoint), since there SharePoint publishing infrastructure as well as many other have been designed to work like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use url rewriting to get rid of the "pages" following Waldek exhaustive explaination [in this blog post](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/friendly-urls-sharepoint-site-4-steps-iis7-url-rewrite-module/)